# Change values inside of CSS's "img" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

This is a part of my HTML file.
How do I change the value of the opacity using JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `style` like:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
  imgs[i].style.opacity = 1
}
```